# Listbox in update control doesn't return correct selected value

Tags: c#, listbox, updatepanel

I'm using a webform with master page.
On the webform, I have an update panel. Inside that is a listbox which is loaded by a datatable.  I have the list do an auto postback, and on SelectedIndexChanged, it's returning the first item, regardless of what I selected.
I noticed if I listed the items on the .aspx page, it returns the correct value.
I'm clueless as to what's happening.

```
<asp:Content ID="SearchBodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="parentup" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="childup1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:ListBox ID="list" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="list_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="type">
            </asp:ListBox>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="text" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="list" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (SecureData sd = new SecureData(true, UserManager.GetLoginToken(true)))
        {
            _dt = sd.GetData("web_searchcriteria_item_listKK", "", 0, 0).Tables["web_searchcriteria_item_listKK"];

            list.DataSource = _dt;
            list.DataBind();
            list.Items.Insert(0, "Select One");
            Session["criteria"] = _dt;
        }
    }
}

protected void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = list.SelectedItem.Text;
    text.Visible = true;

}
```

I really need to get the actual selected item. Can someone help?

Comment: ListBox is in child update panel, It could be possible that it triggered the parent update panel and changed values didn't posted back correctly, try adding ChildrenAsTriggers="False" to parent update panel.

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: I was able to run your code as it is with no issue, could you show the entire Html of your web form?

Comment: The only part of the html I didn't show was the part for the site.master    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Testlistbox.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Testlistbox" %>     When I load from a database, it works on the first click of the listbox, but the second, and subsequent seem almost random.  If I create the table in the c#, it works fine.  I'm beginning to think there is something in the massive amount of code behind that someone did years ago may be messing with this. Thanks for the help, but I've given up on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was just that my datavaluefield was not unique.